# .hgignore ignoring folders with exact names

Tags: version-control, mercurial, repository, tortoisehg, hgignore

This `.hgignore` file ignores the "bin" folders of Visual Studio solutions, which is good. But it also ignores all folders that ends with "bin", for example the folder "testbin".

```
syntax: glob
bin/
```

I tried `^/bin/`, `/bin/` and `^/bin/`, but none of them seem to work.

I want to ignore all folders that are called **exactly** "bin". Not "123bin", or "bin123". How should I configure my .hgignore file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this should work fine if you change the syntax to `syntax: regexp`. Glob syntax doesn't support rooting.
Per `hg help hgignore`:

> Neither glob nor regexp patterns are rooted. A glob-syntax pattern of the form *.c will match a file ending in .c in any directory, and a regexp pattern of the form .c$ will do the same. To root a regexp pattern, start it with ^.

Comment: This was driving me nuts.  Thank you.